# Unity3D - UNet is closes all client connections

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-unet

I developing a fps game with Unet LLAPI and HLAPI network solutions(LLAPI is for lobby server and HLAPI is for game server). When I test servers in localhost, everything is ok but when I test game servers in a dedicated server, the all clients are disconnecting from server unexpectedly. It happens randomly and it does not always happen. When the all clients are disconnect, servers(game server and lobby server) still lives. This problem is happening both on the game server(hlapi) and on the lobby server(llapi). The clients are receive "disconnected by timeout" log after disconnected. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information provided the only answer that I can elaborate is:

Try to set the disconection time out to a higher value, sometimes the "micro-disconections" on the clients are readed on server as "full-disconections" if the Time out is set to a lower value.

Also check your Unity version, as this post suggest: [UNet randomly disconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635674/unet-randomly-disconnects)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, set the answer as the correct answer if you can to help other people ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try a higher port number on Ubuntu. 17000 works but 1700 does not.